# Reclassifying Vector Field using python parser in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am attempting to reclassify a field in ArcMap using python within field calculator.

Below is screenshot of how it is set up. when I run the reclassify I get an error, and my prepossessing results give me an error in syntax. Also attached is the geprocessing results. I am sure this is a very simple fix, I am just very new to python.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

When calling your function, put the fields between exclamation points

```
Reclass(!Map Value!)
```

In your function, use a single word for your variable name

```
def Reclass(Map_Value):
```